# Marshalling a C# Dictionary over COM interop to C++

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, marshalling, com-interop

Is there a good way of marshalling a `Dictionary<string, string>` over COM interop?

Ideas so far include tokenising each `KeyPair` to an array of strings which can be marshalled as a `SafeArray`, or having two string arrays containing keys and values.

Neither seems particularly satisfactory. Any ideas?

Comment: Very unclear.  What kind of operations need to be supported?  If the native code needs to index the dictionary then just write a wrapper class that uses strings instead of a generic K, V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you will find a very elegant solution, since COM interop with non-trivial managed types is always going to involve custom code.

Since your recipient COM client has to know the semantics of the data, you could just marshal to a single SafeArray whose entries are Key1, Value1, Key2, Value2, and so on. Maybe that's just a restatement of the first option you described above, though?